# Saleae analyzer problem

Tags: digital-logic

I have a SPI protocol and i can't analyze it. The at the beginning there is starting transition from 0 to 1 of the clock signal. The  analyzer is treating this transition as information and analyzes from that point. But it is just a hardware clock transition on the power on. It carries no information.
How could i solve that problem. My version is Saleae Logic 1.1.15

Comment: What does the supplier of the logic analyser say?

Comment: `But it is just a hardware clock transition on the power on` Start capturing the SPI signals after the power on..

Comment: The problem is that i'm interested in what happens after power on. I haven't contacted the supplier yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to version 1.1.34, then place a time marker where you want the protocol to start being analyzed, the in the Analyzers section click on the gear button and hit "Re-run starting at timing marker..." and it reanalyzes the data starting from the marker... Hope this helps